# How to merge 2 or more date range into 1

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.6

I am working on a business problem which is complicated.

Anyway, I try to use this example to explain the problem easily.

There is a table with these records:

1. Acct-1  2016-01-01  2016-01-07
2. Acct-1  2016-01-05  2016-01-11
3. Acct-1  2016-01-18  2016-01-24
4. Acct-1  2016-02-02  2016-02-08
5. Acct-1  2016-02-07  2016-02-13

The first column is the account number.  In this example, all are the same account number.  The 2nd and 3rd column is a date range.  All date ranges are exactly 7 days.

I want to make this table more beautiful to "merge" overlapping range together into a single date range.

So, record-1 and record-2 should be merge together to become:

Acct-1 2016-01-01 2016-01-11

Record-3 is standalone, no need to merge with others.

Record-4 and record-5 should be merge together to become:

Acct-1 2016-02-02 2016-02-13

At the end, each account should have records of non-overlapping date range.

Noted that, sometimes we have to merge 2 or 3 or 4 or else records, depending on the overlapping.  There are many different account numbers in the table.

How to do so using SQL statement ?

Temp views can be created to achieve the purpose.

Cheers,

Alvin

Comment: could we used stored procedures, too?

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a solution using user variables. Verified with data you provided and I inserted more data for verification.

To save the query result permanently and keep it accessible later, the result is written into a table tbl_new.

Full demo >>

SQL:

```
-- data preparation
create table tbl(acct varchar(100), start_date date, end_date date);
insert into tbl values
('Acct-1', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-07'),
('Acct-1', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-11'),
('Acct-1', '2016-01-18', '2016-01-24'),
('Acct-1', '2016-02-02', '2016-02-08'),
('Acct-1', '2016-02-07', '2016-02-13'),
('Acct-2', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-07'),
('Acct-2', '2016-01-18', '2016-01-24'),
('Acct-2', '2016-01-02', '2016-02-08');


SELECT * FROM tbl;

-- Need queries
SET @last_acct = '', @last_start_date = '1970-01-01', @last_end_date = '9999-12-31', @group = 1;

CREATE TABLE tbl_new (acct varchar(100), start_date date, end_date date);

INSERT INTO tbl_new 
SELECT 
    acct,
    MIN(start_date) start_date,
    MAX(end_date) end_date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        acct, 
        start_date, 
        end_date,
        CASE 
            WHEN 
                acct = @last_acct AND start_date <= @last_end_date 
            THEN 
                @group
            ELSE
                @group := @group + 1
        END group_num, 
        @last_acct := acct,
        @last_start_date := start_date,
        @last_end_date := end_date
    FROM
        tbl
) tbl2
GROUP BY group_num;

SELECT * FROM tbl_new;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl;
+--------+------------+------------+
| acct   | start_date | end_date   |
+--------+------------+------------+
| Acct-1 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-07 |
| Acct-1 | 2016-01-05 | 2016-01-11 |
| Acct-1 | 2016-01-18 | 2016-01-24 |
| Acct-1 | 2016-02-02 | 2016-02-08 |
| Acct-1 | 2016-02-07 | 2016-02-13 |
| Acct-2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-07 |
| Acct-2 | 2016-01-18 | 2016-01-24 |
| Acct-2 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-02-08 |
+--------+------------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- Need queries
mysql> SET @last_acct = '', @last_start_date = '1970-01-01', @last_end_date = '9999-12-31', @group = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> CREATE TABLE tbl_new (acct varchar(100), start_date date, end_date date);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
mysql> INSERT INTO tbl_new
    -> SELECT
    ->     acct,
    ->     MIN(start_date) start_date,
    ->     MAX(end_date) end_date
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         acct,
    ->         start_date,
    ->         end_date,
    ->         CASE
    ->             WHEN
    ->                 acct = @last_acct AND start_date <= @last_end_date
    ->             THEN
    ->                 @group
    ->             ELSE
    ->                 @group := @group + 1
    ->         END group_num,
    ->         @last_acct := acct,
    ->         @last_start_date := start_date,
    ->         @last_end_date := end_date
    ->     FROM
    ->         tbl
    -> ) tbl2
    -> GROUP BY group_num;

Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_new;
+--------+------------+------------+
| acct   | start_date | end_date   |
+--------+------------+------------+
| Acct-1 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-11 |
| Acct-1 | 2016-01-18 | 2016-01-24 |
| Acct-1 | 2016-02-02 | 2016-02-13 |
| Acct-2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-07 |
| Acct-2 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-02-08 |
+--------+------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Actually, I prefer to use a VIEW to implement this because I have to join the view with other tables to get some other information.  I am not quite sure whether variable can be used in a create view statement.

Comment: @AlvinSIU Updated the posted with a solution to save the result to a table.

Comment: @AlvinSIU does the new solution match your expectation?

Comment: Actually, I need a create view statement so that user can click the view to get the result.  Users does not know the details of writing SQL.  Our table is refreshed everyday with records appending everyday.  Using this method, I have to schedule another job to re-create the tbl_new everyday after refreshing the tbl.  I have to think about some workaround, maybe.

Comment: @DylanSu beautiful solution!