# Overlap the intervals using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, mysql-8.0

```
    +------+------------+------------+
    | id   | start_date | end_date   |
    +------+------------+------------+
    |    1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-12 |
    |    1 | 2019-01-10 | 2019-01-27 |
    |    1 | 2019-01-13 | 2019-01-15 |
    |    1 | 2019-01-18 | 2019-01-25 |
    |    1 | 2019-02-10 | 2019-02-15 |
    |    2 | 2019-01-10 | 2019-01-15 |
    +------+------------+------------+
```

how to merge the overlapping intervals and get the below result in mysql(8.X)?

```
    +------+------------+------------+
    | id   | start_date | end_date   |
    +------+------------+------------+
    |    1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-27 |
    |    1 | 2019-02-10 | 2019-02-15 |
    |    2 | 2019-01-10 | 2019-01-15 |
    +------+------------+------------+
```

Below are the commands that can be used in mysql to create the table =>

```
    insert into interval_dates(id, start_date, end_date) values(1, '2019-01-01', '2019-01-12');
    insert into interval_dates(id, start_date, end_date) values(1, '2019-01-10', '2019-01-27');
    insert into interval_dates(id, start_date, end_date) values(1, '2019-01-13', '2019-01-15');
    insert into interval_dates(id, start_date, end_date) values(1, '2019-01-18', '2019-01-25');
    insert into interval_dates(id, start_date, end_date) values(1, '2019-02-10', '2019-02-15');
    insert into interval_dates(id, start_date, end_date) values(2, '2019-01-10', '2019-01-15');
```

can you please share any elegant solution without inserting into intermediate table in mysql(8.X)?

Comment: It seems a little odd to employ @variables inside a cte.

Comment: If you have working code and are looking for advice on improvements, [codereview.se] is a better site.

Comment: There's also this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625527/how-to-merge-2-or-more-date-range-into-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check:

```sql
SELECT id, start_date, MAX(end_date) end_date
FROM ( SELECT id,
              @p_start := CASE WHEN (start_date > @p_end) OR (@p_id < id)
                               THEN start_date
                               ELSE @p_start
                               END start_date,
              @p_end := CASE WHEN (end_date > @p_end) OR (@p_id < id)
                             THEN end_date
                             ELSE @p_end
                             END end_date,
              @p_id := id
       FROM mytable, ( SELECT @p_id := MIN(id)-1, 
                              @p_start := MIN(start_date) - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 
                              @p_end := MIN(start_date) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                       FROM mytable ) variables
       ORDER BY id, start_date, end_date ) subquery
GROUP BY id, start_date;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4a9d16fd1675652c9d44bfbd7f5b669d) (applicable even in 5.6).

I have not yet been able to find the source data that produces the wrong result.

Comment: @KishorekumarYakkala *it 's not working with dataset* Do you need to solve your problem, or the fact that we couldn't solve is enough? Execure inner subquery only. Investigate the result. Find the problem point and explain, what is the kind of incorrectness and what data particularity causes it.

Comment: `+------+------------+------------+----------+
| id   | start_date | end_date   | group_id |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
|    1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-27 |        1 |
|    1 | 2019-02-10 | 2019-02-15 |        2 |
|    2 | 2019-02-10 | 2019-02-15 |        1 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
`

Comment: @KishorekumarYakkala This output is correct, overlappings are removed. What it must tell about?

Comment: if you see the last record. it's not matching.
expected: 2, 2019-**01**-10, 2019-**01**-15, 1
actual: 2, 2019-**02**-10, 2019-**02**-15, 1

Comment: @KishorekumarYakkala Oops... what a stupid misprint. Edited. Check now.

Comment: WOW. So fast and it's working as expected now.. Thanks a ton @Akina

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to window functions, why not use them? But if the [`LAG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) function is not good enough, I can offer the following 2 options:

```sql
with
  a as (
    select id, start_date as ts, 1 as evt from mytable
    union all
    select id, end_date as ts, -1 from mytable
  ),
  b as (
    select *,
      sum(evt) over(partition by id order by ts, evt desc
                    rows unbounded preceding) as qnt
    from a
  ),
  c as (
    select id, ts,
      floor((row_number() over(partition by id order by ts) - 1) / 2) as grp
    from b
    where (evt = 1 and qnt = 1) or (evt = -1 and qnt = 0)
  )
select id, min(ts) as start_date, max(ts) as end_date
from c
group by id, grp;
```

```sql
with
  a as (
    select *,
      case
        when start_date <= max(end_date) over(
                             partition by id
                             order by start_date, end_date
                             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                           )
        then 0
        else 1
      end as started
    from mytable
  ),
  b as (
    select *,
      sum(started) over(partition by id
                        order by start_date, end_date
                        rows unbounded preceding) as grp
    from a
  )
select id, min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
from b
group by id, grp;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b307510fbe6295df46b3ac7814b24db)

I also want to point out the possibility of using [Named Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-named-windows.html) in MySql 8.